# Phalcon use Oracle views

Tags: oracle, phalcon

In a Phalcon project, I have multiple database in Oracle and mySQL with number of tables and views. Created models for corresponding tables and views. But unable to access views. I initialize in model below:

```
public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setConnectionService('dbBznes');
        $this->setSchema('POLICY');
        $this->setSource("BUSINESS_ALL");
    }
```

Comment: I assume you have a service `dbBznes` on your DI which connects to Oracle through Incubator's [Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Oracle](https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Adapter) class and you have the PDO OCI extension enabled, correct? Are you able to connect to Oracle from Phalcon? Or is this merely an issue of juggling [two connections at once](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/db-models#setting-multiple-databases). Are you struggling with accessing Oracle features through PDO, or are you running into an issue with limitations in Phalcon's ORM?

Comment: Please show us what you're using.

Comment: I have no problem to access table of multiple database. And I am able to access Oracle table but not the views.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using Oracle Incubator with PDO OCI extension.  if I use `$this->setSource("table1");` is working but `$this->setSource("view1");` showing error.

Comment: Sounds like a metadata issue. Have you tried using the incubator dialect for Oracle?https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/master/Library/Phalcon/Db/Dialect#oracle

Comment: Also I used `'dialectClass' => Phalcon\Db\Dialect\Oracle::class,`; Showing error `Table 'schema'.'view1' doesn't exist in database when dumping meta-data for vokuro\Models\modelName`

Comment: To get around the meta data issue, you might try a different strategy for the metadata. Introspection is the default and queries the database while Annotations checks comments on the model: https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.3/reference/models-metadata.html#database-introspection-strategy
You could also manually add a metaData method to your model to save the ORM from having to hit a non-existent table for its data types. The ORM need to do this extra query in order to know the data types for the fields in the table.

Comment: You could actually even implement your own strategy. The error you get is here: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/metadata/strategy/introspection.zep#L67
So you'd just need to create your own custom strategy class which implements Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\StrategyInterface, then add a getMetaData and getColumnMaps method. With the incubator dialect for Oracle, you can use methods like `viewExists`, describeColumns, describeIndexes. If you wire those in correctly, you should be able to add "View" support.

Comment: You can also implement phalcon's introspection strategy logic within your own custom `metaData` method directly on your model. This zephir  is really simple to write as PHP: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/metadata/strategy/introspection.zep#L40
Then where it checks `tableExists` if it fails, you can also add a `viewExists` check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, this is apparently a metadata issue and the default metadata strategy is introspection and is attempting to check if the table exists. You can set up your own metadata strategy like so:

```
$di['modelsMetadata'] = function()
{
    $metadata = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Memory();
    $metadata->setStrategy(
        new MyIntrospectionStrategy()
    );

    return $metadata;
};
```

"Memory" in this case means don't use any sort of metadata caching. This goes off into another tangent as you can cache in many ways for more speed in production, etc.

As for the `MyIntrospectionStrategy` class above, it represents your own class based on Phalcon's Introspection strategy which attempts to analyze the database to figure out the fields and their types involved with the table.

I believe I converted [Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\Strategy\Introspection](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/mvc/model/metadata/strategy/introspection.zep) from Zephir to PHP correctly as follows:

```
class MyIntrospectionStrategy implements \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData\StrategyInterface
{

    public final function getMetaData(\Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface $model, \Phalcon\DiInterface $dependencyInjector)
    {
        $schema = $model->getSchema();
        $table = $model->getSource();

        $readConnection = $model->getReadConnection();



        if( !$readConnection->tableExists($table, $schema) )
        {
            if($schema)
            {
                $completeTable = $schema . "'.'" . $table;
            } else {
                $completeTable = $table;
            }

            throw new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception(
                "Table '" . $completeTable . "' doesn't exist in database when dumping meta-data for " . get_class($model)
            );
        }



        $columns = $readConnection->describeColumns($table, $schema);

        if( !count($columns) )
        {

            if($schema)
            {
                $completeTable = $schema . "'.'" . $table;
            } else {
                $completeTable = $table;
            }

            /**
             * The table not exists
             */
            throw new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception(
                "Cannot obtain table columns for the mapped source '" . completeTable . "' used in model " . get_class(model)
            );
        }



        $attributes = [];
        $primaryKeys = [];
        $nonPrimaryKeys = [];
        $numericTyped = [];
        $notNull = [];
        $fieldTypes = [];
        $fieldBindTypes = [];
        $automaticDefault = [];
        $identityField = false;
        $defaultValues = [];
        $emptyStringValues = [];

        foreach($columns as $column)
        {

            $fieldName = $column->getName();
            $attributes[] = $fieldName;

            if ($column->isPrimary() === true)
            {
                $primaryKeys[] = $fieldName;
            } else {
                $nonPrimaryKeys[] = $fieldName;
            }

            if ($column->isNumeric() === true)
            {
                $numericTyped[$fieldName] = true;
            }

            if ($column->isNotNull() === true)
            {
                $notNull[] = $fieldName;
            }

            if ($column->isAutoIncrement() === true)
            {
                $identityField = $fieldName;
            }

            $fieldTypes[$fieldName] = $column->getType();

            $fieldBindTypes[$fieldName] = $column->getBindType();

            $defaultValue = $column->getDefault();
            if ($defaultValue !== null || $column->isNotNull() === false)
            {
                if ( !$column->isAutoIncrement() )
                {
                    $defaultValues[$fieldName] = $defaultValue;
                }
            }
        }

        return [
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_ATTRIBUTES               => $attributes,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_PRIMARY_KEY              => $primaryKeys,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_NON_PRIMARY_KEY          => $nonPrimaryKeys,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_NOT_NULL                 => $notNull,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_DATA_TYPES               => $fieldTypes,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_DATA_TYPES_NUMERIC       => $numericTyped,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_IDENTITY_COLUMN          => $identityField,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_DATA_TYPES_BIND          => $fieldBindTypes,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_AUTOMATIC_DEFAULT_INSERT => $automaticDefault,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_AUTOMATIC_DEFAULT_UPDATE => $automaticDefault,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_DEFAULT_VALUES           => $defaultValues,
            \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\MetaData::MODELS_EMPTY_STRING_VALUES      => $emptyStringValues
        ];

    }


    public final function getColumnMaps(\Phalcon\Mvc\ModelInterface $model, \Phalcon\DiInterface $dependencyInjector)
    {
        $orderedColumnMap = null;
        $reversedColumnMap = null;

        if (method_exists($model, 'columnMap'))
        {

            $userColumnMap = $model->columnMap();
            if ( gettype($userColumnMap) != 'array')
            {
                // Bad grammer directly in cphalcon :sadface:
                throw new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception('columnMap() not returned an array');
            }

            $reversedColumnMap = [];
            $orderedColumnMap = $userColumnMap;
            foreach($userColumnMap as $name => $userName)
            {
                $reversedColumnMap[$userName] = $name;
            }
        }

        return [$orderedColumnMap, $reversedColumnMap];
    }


}
```

I have not tested this.

As far as adding support for views to be treated like tables, the change might be as simple as:

Before:

```
if( !$readConnection->tableExists($table, $schema) )
```

After:

```
if( !$readConnection->tableExists($table, $schema) && !$readConnection->viewExists($table, $schema) )
```

If this doesn't work due to logic choking with describeColumns, you might need to write something specific for working with views in Oracle for this dialect.

As far as other solutions, you can provide your own metadata method directly on the model by specifying your own`metaData` method directly on it.

Another solution is to use annotations instead of introspection for metadata.
Then you'd place your metadata as comments in the code for Phalcon to parse.

If you continue to run into problems with Database Views, just run it as raw SQL rather than attempting to use the ORM to do it. You can simply define a new method on your model to run the raw SQL.